# If $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and analytic off $[-1,1]$ then is entire.

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, analytic-functions, entire-functions

This is a problem from Complex Variable (Conway's book) 2nd ed.

(Section 4.4) 9. Show that if $f: \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function such that $f$ is analytic off $[-1,1]$ then $f$ is an entire function.

I already have a solution by Morera's theorem that split this problem in 5 cases. I think this solution is too long and I'm trying to solve this using a different approach. Any ideas ?

Comment: Consider $$g_r(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert \zeta - 15\rvert = r} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}\,d\zeta$$ (for $\lvert z-15\rvert < r$). How does $g_r(z)$ depend on $r$?

Comment: If (for fixed $z$) you can see that $g_r(z)$ doesn't depend on $z$, it follows that $f$ is entire, since $g_r(z) = f(z)$ for $r < 14$ by the integral formula.

Comment: Ok. I'm trying to get your point. Why you choose 15 ?, and how can I know that $g_r(z)$ is entire to conclude that if $f(z) = g_r(z)$ is entire ?. Where we use the continuity of f and and the analycity on $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$. ? Sorry if my questions seems obvious to you.

Comment: I know that $f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(\psi)}{\psi - z}$ for some $\gamma(t) =  a+ re^{it}, t \in [0,2\pi]$ where $f$ is analytic in $G$ and $\overline{B}(a;r) \subseteq G$. And you choose 15 and 14 because the ball is not touching $[-1,1]$.

Comment: The $15$ is completely arbitrary. All we need is a centre $z_0$ that lies outside the problematic segment $[-1,1]$, so that we know $g_r(z) = f(z)$ for small $r > 0$ and $\lvert z - z_0\rvert < r$. The integral theorem gives the independence of $g_r(z)$ from $r$ for $r > \lvert z_0\rvert + 1$ (for $z$ so that all considered $g_r$ are defined at $z$), so $h(z) := \lim\limits_{r\to\infty} g_r(z)$ defines an entire function. For $r < \lvert z_0\rvert < 1$, $g_r(z) = f(z)$ where $g_r$ is defined. Since $f$ is continuous and holomorphic outside $[-1,1]$,

Comment: one can move the contour over that segment without changing the integral (for $\lvert z-z_0\rvert$ small enough), so $h = f$ on a neighbourhood of $z_0$. The identity theorem says $h = f$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$, and continuity says $h = f$ everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Daniel Fischer, I used a Cauchy integral formula approach. Let $\gamma (t) = 2e^{it}, 0\le t \le 2\pi.$ For small $\epsilon>0$ let $R_\epsilon=[-1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]\times [-\epsilon,\epsilon].$ Consider $\partial R_\epsilon$ as a contour in the natural way, oriented clockwise.

Let $z \in D(0,2)\setminus [-1,1].$ Then $z\notin R_\epsilon$ for small $\epsilon >0.$ For such $\epsilon$ we have by Cauchy

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\left ( \int_{\gamma + R_\epsilon} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw\right ).$$

Verify that the integral over $R_\epsilon \to 0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$ (here using the continuity of $f$). Thus we have

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\left ( \int_\gamma  \frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw\right )$$

for all $z \in D(0,2)\setminus [-1,1].$ But the last integral defines a holomorphic function in all of $D(0,2).$ Simply by continuity, $f$ equals this integral in all of $D(0,2)$ and we're done.

Comment: I can understand everything except the last step.

Comment: @RichardClare what do you mean by the last step?

Comment: Simply by continuity, f equals this integral in all of D(0,2) and we're done

Comment: @RichardClare  Call the integral $I(z).$ Then $I$ is holomorphic in $D(0,2).$ And we've seen $f(z)= I(z)$ in $D(0,2)\setminus [-1,1].$ The latter set is dense in $D(0,2).$ So you have two continuous functions on $D(0,2)$, $f(z)$ and $I(z),$ that agree on a dense subset of $D(0,2).$ Hence these two functions agree in $D(0,2),$ and therefore $f$ is holomorphic in $D(0,2).$

Comment: Thank you. The only two points that are not very clear is how can I show that the integrals tends to 0 as $R_{\epsilon} \to 0$ and how this function I(Z) is analytic in D(0,2). All other steps are now clear.

Comment: @RichardClare  For the the contour integral over $\partial R_\epsilon,$ note that the "big part" of it is $\int_{-1}^1 f(t+i\epsilon)\,dt - \int_{-1}^1 f(t-i\epsilon)\,dt.$ The limit of this is $0$ by the uniform continuity of $f.$ This is really the only place that the nice straight interval $[-1,1].$ enters the picture. The other parts of the contour integral clearly $\to 0.$ I think you must have seen the proof that $I(z)$ is holomorphic in $D(0,2)$ at some point. This is how you show that holomorphic functions have power series!

Comment: what parameteriztion of $$R_1 := (-1-\epsilon) +i\epsilon \to (1+\epsilon) +i\epsilon $$ are you using to transform the integral to say $$ \int_{R_1} \dfrac{f(w)}{w-z} = \int_{-1}^1 f(t+i\epsilon)dt \;\; ?$$

Comment: @alpastor I don't mention $R_1.$ I mention $\partial R_\epsilon.$

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean by "the big part" of $\partial R_\epsilon$? I thought you meant the top and bottom of $R_\epsilon$.

Comment: @alpastor I defined "big part" in my comment.