# Show $f$ (assumed continuous and analytic apart from a line segment) is analytic in domain $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show $f$ (assumed continuous and analytic apart from a line segment) is analytic in domain $D$

> If $f$ is continuous in a domain $D\subset\mathbb{C}$, and $f$ is analytic in $D \setminus L$ where $L$ is a line segment ($L \subset D$), then show $f$ is analytic in $D$.

I guess I have to use Morera's Theorem to prove this. But, I'm not exactly sure how to approach this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have added a (very) detailed answer for you. Please let me know if you have any questions! If it's helpful - don't forget to accept/upvote as you please. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I shall prove a more general result for you, i.e. by replacing *line segment* with *line*. You are right, the idea is to use Morera's theorem. Note that (in the proof below) you can replace $\mathbb C$ by any domain $D$, the proof stays the same. If needed, the domain $D$ can be brought closer to the real line (so that I may assume $L$ is a subset of the real line) by means of translation; which is a homeomorphism. Lastly, I have used *"holomorphic"* instead of *"analytic"*, but these are equivalent notions. The essence of the argument lies in *how to use* Morera's theorem, as you shall see.
$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}$
$\renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$
$\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}$

---

> **Theorem.** If a continuous function $f:\C\to\C$ is holomorphic outside a line $L$ in $\mathbb C$ then it is holomorphic everywhere.

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $L$ is the real line. This can be arranged by means of an affine transformation. In fact, it is easy to see that the reasoning that follows works for any line $L$ in $\C$. In other words, it is affine-invariant. We shall use Morera's theorem to show that $f$ is entire.

> **Morera's Theorem.** Let $G$ be an open, connected subset of $\C$, and let $f: G\to \C$ be a continuous function such that $\int_T f(z) dz = 0$ for every triangular path $T$ in $G$; then $f$ is analytic in $G$.

In our case, $G = \C$. Let $T$ be a triangle (without interior) in $\C$. $\int_T f(z) dz = 0$ for every $T$ contained entirely in $\mathbb H_1 = \{z\in \C: \Im z > 0\}$ or $\mathbb H_2 = \{z\in \C: \Im z < 0\}$ by Cauchy's theorem. It remains to consider the case where $T$ intersects the real line. Decomposing $T$ into smaller triangles, it suffices to consider the case where $T$ has an edge on the real line. $\color{red}{^1}$ Without loss of generality, suppose $T$ lies in $\overline{\mathbb H_1}$. Let $T$ have vertices $A,B$ and $C$ as in the figure below. We can find a compact set $K \subset \C$ containing $T$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(K)$ is compact, hence bounded. That is, there exists $M > 0$ such that $|f(z)| \le M$ for all $z\in K$.

[image]

Construct a line segment $B_\delta C_\delta$ parallel to $BC$, at height $\delta > 0$ above the base. Drop perpendiculars $B_\delta B_\delta'$ and $C_\delta C_\delta'$ on $BC$.
$$\int_{ABC} f(z)\, dz = \int_{AB_\delta C_\delta}  f(z)\, dz + \int_{B_\delta BC C_\delta}  f(z)\, dz$$
By Cauchy's theorem, $$\int_{AB_\delta C_\delta}  f(z)\, dz = 0$$
as $AB_\delta C_\delta$ lies entirely inside $\mathbb H_1$, where $f$ is holomorphic. So, $$\int_{ABC} f(z)\, dz = \int_{B_\delta BC C_\delta}  f(z)\, dz$$
Since $\delta > 0$ is arbitrary, take limits as $\delta\to 0$. Then,
$$\int_{ABC} f(z)\, dz = \lim_{\delta\to 0} \int_{B_\delta BC C_\delta}  f(z)\, dz$$
Also,
$$\int_{B_\delta BC C_\delta}  f(z)\, dz = \int_{B_\delta B B_\delta'}  f(z)\, dz + \int_{B_\delta B_\delta' C_\delta' C_\delta}  f(z)\, dz + \int_{C_\delta C_\delta' C}  f(z)\, dz$$
As $\delta\to 0$, $\operatorname{len} (B_\delta B B_\delta') \to 0$ and $\operatorname{len} (C_\delta C_\delta' C)\to 0$.
We have $$\left| \int_{B_\delta B B_\delta'} f(z)\, dz \right| \le \sup_{z\in B_\delta B B_\delta'} |f(z)| \operatorname{len}(B_\delta B B_\delta') \le M \operatorname{len}(B_\delta B B_\delta') \xrightarrow{\delta\to 0} 0$$
and $$\left| \int_{C_\delta C_\delta' C} f(z)\, dz \right| \le \sup_{z\in C_\delta C_\delta' C} |f(z)| \operatorname{len}(C_\delta C_\delta' C) \le M \operatorname{len}(C_\delta C_\delta' C) \xrightarrow{\delta\to 0} 0$$
Moreover, $$\int_{B_\delta B_\delta' C_\delta' C_\delta}  f(z)\, dz = \int_{B_\delta' C_\delta'}  f(z)\, dz + \int_{C_\delta B_\delta}  f(z)\, dz + \int_{B_\delta B_\delta'}  f(z)\, dz + \int_{C_\delta' C_\delta}  f(z)\, dz$$
As $\delta\to 0$, $\operatorname{len}(B_\delta B_\delta') \to 0$ and $\operatorname{len}(C_\delta' C_\delta) \to 0$. We have
$$\left|\int_{B_\delta B_\delta'} f(z)\, dz \right| \le \sup_{z\in B_\delta B_\delta'} |f(z)| \operatorname{len}(B_\delta B_\delta') \le M \operatorname{len}(B_\delta B_\delta') \xrightarrow{\delta\to 0} 0$$
and $$\left|\int_{C_\delta' C_\delta} f(z)\, dz \right| \le \sup_{z\in C_\delta' C_\delta} |f(z)| \operatorname{len}(C_\delta' C_\delta) \le M \operatorname{len}(C_\delta' C_\delta) \xrightarrow{\delta\to 0} 0$$
Lastly, $$\int_{B_\delta' C_\delta'} f(z)\, dz + \int_{C_\delta B_\delta} f(z)\, dz \xrightarrow{\delta\to 0} 0$$
as the segments $B_\delta C_\delta$ and $B_\delta' C_\delta'$ both approach $BC$, as $\delta\to 0$.$\color{red}{^2}$ Therefore,
$$\int_{ABC} f(z)\, dz = \lim_{\delta\to 0} \int_{B_\delta BC C_\delta}  f(z)\, dz = 0$$
We conclude that $$\int_T f(z)\, dz = 0$$ for every triangle in $\C$. By Morera's theorem, $f$ is holomorphic on $\C$, i.e. $f$ is entire.

---

*Footnotes:*
$\color{red}{1.}$ This argument is standard; see, for example, the proof of Schwarz Reflection Principle.
$\color{red}{2.}$ A similar argument is seen in the proof of Cauchy's integral formulae (the keyhole contour construction).

---

*Related Posts:* See [Post 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373844/if-f-mathbbc-to-mathbbc-is-continuous-and-analytic-off-1-1-then-i), [Post 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220464/continuous-on-whole-complex-plane-and-analytic-in-z-mid-operatornameimz).