# If $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous and analytic off $[-1,1]$ then $f$ is entire.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I know this question had already been asked and answered here.

[If $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and analytic off $[-1,1]$ then is entire.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373844/if-f-mathbbc-to-mathbbc-is-continuous-and-analytic-off-1-1-then-i)

However I was trying power series approach.
By analyticity, $f$ can be expanded in power series around $\iota$ in radius of convergence $1$.
Take the sequence $\frac{\iota}{n}\to0$. Then $f(\frac{\iota}{n})$ is given by power series $\sum a_k(z-\iota)^k$. Can we take limit inside power series? Then $f$ will be analytic at $0$. Similarly on other points of $[-1,1]$.

Problem I am facing is uniform convergence of power series is guaranteed inside open ball.
Also Abel's theorem does not help much as I need to go to reverse direction, i.e., using continuity of $f$ to ensure convergence of power series.

Comment: There's a simple argument that the Laurent Series at $0$ for $1\lt \vert z \vert \lt \infty$ is in fact a power series, giving the result.  But I don't see a way to progress your argument.